# installing ruby build using rvben on centOS 6.6

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I followed this instruction on how to install ruby build on centos 6.6

[Ruby Installing Instuction](http://mmclub.github.io/blog/2014/03/30/install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos/)

but I got this error.

[image]

How do you fix this error?

Comment: it's failing to build a native extension. normally you need to have development tools installed. Can you share full log?

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure the problem you are having. The yellow line (log file) would be good to show. However, I have attempted using a script to install ruby with rbenv on CentOS 6.6 with Vagrant provisioning. It is no difference whether it is Vagrant or straight ISO disk installation. NOTE: This is system wide install.

Usually I use RVM for user based install. (Because I don't know how to use RVM to install ruby on system wide level recognised when installing, say, librarian-puppet).

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su

yum -y install openssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel libcurl-devel git gcc g++ make automake autoconf

pushd /usr/local
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git
mkdir -p rbenv/{shims,versions,plugins}
groupadd rbenv
chgrp -R rbenv rbenv
chmod -R g+rwxXs rbenv

pushd /usr/local/rbenv/plugins
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
chgrp -R rbenv ruby-build
chmod -R g+rwxs ruby-build
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-default-gems.git
chgrp -R rbenv rbenv-default-gems
chmod -R g+rwxs rbenv-default-gems

cat << 'EOF' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv"
export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
EOF

cat << EOF >> /usr/local/rbenv/default-gems
bundler
rbenv-rehash
EOF

source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

rbenv install 2.2.2
rbenv global 2.2.2
```